# What is the best way to do browser popup alerts?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Those little notification panels that appear for a few seconds even when the browser is behind another window.  Slack does it.

Are there any third party directives or jquery libraries out there?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a toast notification. Search for "toast" at the [JQuery Plugin Registry](http://plugins.jquery.com/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11619061)

Comment: @maxhb this answer is fine as it is. It would be impossible to include "the essential" parts of the linked to content. Rather than delete this answer, the question itself should be closed instead.

Comment: Have a look at how the answer by @micronyks is written. Provide a simple example and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `Toastr` library ***[example  with Angular2](https://plnkr.co/edit/AJbEYDxncUQ67gIstgfs?p=preview)***

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template: `
      <button (click)="displayToastr()">Display Toastr</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayToastr() {
    toastr.info('I am here for few seconds');
  }
}
```

This is how I used `Toastr` ***[with Angular1 ( had made it for angular1 with directives)](http://micronyks.github.io/Angular-Notification/)***

Comment: great work +1, for this we just have to add `src/toastr.d.ts` file ? or something else ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Have you checked index.html? just add `toastr.js` and its css. typing is not necessary for it. still typing is available.

Comment: hey @micronyks when i write this code `toastr.info('xyz');` in my .ts file it shows warning message with red underline `cannot find name toaster. any` how to remove this ? i can remove this by declaring `declare var toastr : any;` but this is not correct way i think is't it ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AJbEYDxncUQ67gIstgfs?p=preview can you show me here. Its not necessary. But its good to use d.ts file as you are working with typescript. But still its fine.

Comment: how to show warning message on plnkr ? i dont think we can reproduce warning message on plnkr is't it ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AJbEYDxncUQ67gIstgfs?p=preview please check and let me know what else you want.

Comment: your code works fine no doubt. i just want to ask you to remove these red color underline warning, also which is handle by declaring `declare var toastr: any` i just want to know is it a right way ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I don't understand what you are trying to say. what do you mean by `red color underline`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108796/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-micronyks).

Answer (score 1):

Try Alertify
http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

This is easy to use and looks very nice

Answer (score 1):

This little notification panels are called as toasts.You have tagged the question under angular2 hence suggesting you the following two packages:
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster

Comment: first one is not working have you any working demo of same ?  throws error `system is not defined`

Comment: @PardeepJain Check the answer below with example from micronyks